# What's the recommended way to serialize `tf.Module`s?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0

I have a `tf.Module` class that contains a (non-picklable) `tf.keras.Model` as a submodule. I wonder what the recommended way to serialize the `tf.Module` in this case is?

I considered two ways:

1. Using something similar to `tf.keras.Model.save`. I was hoping that maybe `tf.Module`s would be able to save the nested modules the same way as `tf.Model.save` does. The `tf.Module` does not have such thing implemented, however.
2. Pickling, which would be an easy way to serialize the `tf.Module`, but I can't do that because the `tf.keras.Model` is unpicklable.

Here's an example code that currently fails:

```py
import pickle

import tensorflow as tf


class TestModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model


def main():
    x = tf.keras.layers.Input((3, ))
    y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)
    # Note, model *is not* picklable.
    model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)

    _ = model(tf.random.uniform((1, 3)))

    module_1 = TestModule(model)
    module_2 = pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(module_1))

    for variable_1, variable_2 in zip(module_1.model.trainable_variables,
                                      module_2.model.trainable_variables):
        tf.debugging.assert_equal(variable_1, variable_2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Should I write custom pickle functionality (e.g. `__{get,set}state__`) for each `tf.Module` or should I create a similar `.save` method that `keras.Model`s have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Saved Model Format](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/saved_model#exporting_custom_models) to save a custom `tf.Module` subclass.

The following works for Tensorflow 2.1:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

class TestModule(tf.Module):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model


x = tf.keras.layers.Input((3, ))
y = tf.keras.layers.Dense(5)(x)
model = tf.keras.Model(x, y)
module_1 = TestModule(model)

tf.saved_model.save(module_1, "./foo")
```

To load back:
`imported = tf.saved_model.load("foo")`

The assertion
`module_1 == imported` (or similar) will raise `AssertionError` as after loading we are dealing with a different Tensorflow Object. We can however iterate over model's weights and compare them element wise:

```py
original_weights = module_1.model.weights
imported_weights = imported.model.variables.weights

for weight_idx, _ in enumerate(original_weights):
  assert (
      original_weights[weight_idx].numpy() == imported_weights[weight_idx].numpy()
      ).all()
```

Comment: This seems like a good way to go. I'll wait for a bit to see if any other useful answers come around. One additional question regarding this though: it seems like `imported` is missing the `trainable_variables` attribute even though it exists in `module_1`. Any ideas why that might be? I get an `error AttributeError: '_UserObject' object has no attribute 'trainable_variables'`. I opened a github issue for this since it seems like a bug to me: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/36021.

Comment: That is true. The `trainable_variables` only exist in the `model` subpart of `imported`. Although, I can't answer why as I don't know that many serialization details.